# BeautifulSoup isn't returning a url when we query for the src of the img tag

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, urllib

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

url = "https://amazon-asin.com/asincheck/?product_id=B000JMLBHU"
req = request.urlopen(url)
soap = BeautifulSoup(req,'html.parser')
soap.find('img',{'class':'resp-img'})['ng-src']
```

I'm using ng-src because, with only 'src', it returns nothing. But, with ng-src, it returns this:

```
'{{data.product_details.image_url}}'
```

Why it doesn't return the url? How can i scrape the url of this image?

Comment: The url is loaded in javascript

Comment: up vote to if you are satisfied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:program/geckodriver')
url = "https://amazon-asin.com/asincheck/?product_id=B000JMLBHU"

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img.resp-img').get_attribute('ng-src'))
driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51sPuWd2JbL.jpg
```

Note yo need [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and in this code geckodriver is set to be imported from `c:/program/geckodriver.exe`